# Docker-compose permission error, chown not working

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx, devops

Trying to set a laravel project with redis, mysql and mongodb. Using docker-compose to set docker containers, but 127.0.0.1 throws `The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied`. Chown'ing directory but owner of /var/www/html inside 'app' container is root, not www-data. How can I fix it?

Dockerfile

```
ARG PHP_VERSION
FROM php:7-fpm-alpine
ARG APP_ENV
ARG REMOTE_WORKING_DIR
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache $PHPIZE_DEPS \
   build-base shadow nano curl gcc git bash \
   php7 \
   ...installing dependencies...
...redis & mongodb...
...php settings...
...installing composer...
RUN rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
RUN apk add shadow && usermod -u 1000 www-data && groupmod -g 1000 www-data
COPY . $REMOTE_WORKING_DIR
RUN sudo chown -R www-data:www-data $REMOTE_WORKING_DIR
USER www-data
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
 app:
   build:
     context: ./docker/php
     args:
       APP_ENV: ${APP_ENV}
       PHP_VERSION: ${PHP_VERSION}
       REMOTE_WORKING_DIR: ${REMOTE_WORKING_DIR}
   container_name: app
   restart: always
   env_file: .env
   ports:
     ...
   links:
     - redis
   networks:
     ...
   volumes:
     - ${LOCAL_WORKING_DIR}:${REMOTE_WORKING_DIR}
     - ./docker/php/config/xdebug.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini

 nginx:
   ...
   volumes:
     - ${LOCAL_WORKING_DIR}:${REMOTE_WORKING_DIR}
     - ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
     - ./docker/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
     - ./docker/nginx/ssl/:/etc/nginx/ssl/
   ports:
     ...
   depends_on:
     - app
   networks:
     ...

 redis:
 ...

networks:
...
```

Comment: try - ${LOCAL_WORKING_DIR}:${REMOTE_WORKING_DIR}:RW

Comment: is it fixed ? I got the same error